# Printing 2 pages per sheet results in 4 pages

Tags: pdf, printing

Every now and then, I use the "Layout" option in macOS's print dialog to fit two pages on a sheet, for instance when printing presentation slides. For some reason, this sometimes leads to 4 pages being printed per sheet, rendering the slides hardly readable. Happened twice to me today.

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to prevent it?

### Update

In response to Tetsujin's comment:

- I'm running the latest macOS Sierra 10.12.4 (16E195) but I've been experiencing this issue with previous versions of macOS (formerly OS X) as well so I don't think it matters.
- I print from Preview and Safari and the problem occurs in both cases.
- I usually print two A5s onto one A4. I'm fairly certain, there's no spilling over.
- The print dialog shows the correct number of pages.
- "Is this happening at the app or at the printer?" - Not sure what is meant.

Comment: We need a lot more information - what OS; what App; are you checking the data is formatted to fill the page & not spilling over [eg are you trying to print US Letter onto A4 paper]; does the preview show the correct page count; is this happening at the app or at the printer??

Comment: Re: app or printer - maybe try an output as PDF & see if the repagination happens at that stage. (edit) a further point - is that a warning triangle on your printer? Do you know why?

Comment: @Tetsujin That works just fine. I get two pages per sheet as expected which is why I suspect that there might some issue with piping the output to the printer, i.e. some miscommunication between macOS and the printer drivers.

Comment: I'd be inclined to check the drivers - https://support.apple.com/HT201465 has a list of supported printers & links to manufacturer's web site

Comment: @Tetsujin The printers I use are listed. Since this issue occurred with several printers from different manufacturers I'm guessing the problem is on macOS's part.

Comment: When this problem occurs with a particular file, does it always occur with that file? For example, say you're printing a doc called _Introduction.pdf_ and the problem occurs. If you print the same doc again, whether immediately or a week later, does the problem still occur? Or is this an intermittent issue even with the same document? Also, have you noticed the same issue printing from other software? For example, if you created the document in MS Word before PDF'ing it and printing from Preview, is the problem also replicated if printing the original document from MS Word?

Comment: @Monomeeth Yes, the problem persists for repeated printing of the same document. (I never tried more than twice to avoid wasting paper.) I don't use Word and Pages only infrequently. Never tried printing two pages per sheet from the latter, I'm afraid. But the issue occurs both when printing from Preview and Safari.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. As for MS Word, I was only using that as an example because I'm wondering whether the original application you've used to create the document (_whatever_ it is) is able to print the document correctly in its native format, or whether the problem only occurs when you're printing the PDF version and/or only when printing from Preview or Safari?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. The only way I manage to print 2 pages is printing it as a two-page layout PDF (which generates the expected two-pages per sheet layout), and then printing this as a one page per sheet. If I print directly, it will print 4 pages per sheet when I specify 2. This happens for the last 3 Mac OS versions, independent of the printer or program (I just checked with a PDF from Safari).

This happens from Sierra up to Movaje (as of now).

Comment: Funny, that’s exactly how I ended up working around the problem.

Comment: So, as of March, 2019, there’s no known fix except for the “print-to-pdf-first” workaround.

Comment: As of 2024 the problem persists, and saving the two-page layout PDF and printing is as a one page sheet is still the best solution.